# Scrape web with a query

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape impact factors of journals from a particular website or entire web. I have been searching for something close but hard luck..

This is the first time I am trying web scrape with python. I am trying to find the simplest way.

I have a list of ISSN numbers belong to Journals and I want to retrieve the impact factor values of them from web or a particular site. The list has more than 50K values so manually searching the values is practically hard .

Input type

```
Index,JOURNALNAME,ISSN,Impact Factor 2015,URL,ABBV,SUBJECT
1,4OR-A Quarterly Journal of Operations Research,1619-4500,,,4OR Q J OPER RES,Management Science
2,Aaohn Journal,0891-0162,,,AAOHN J,
3,Aapg Bulletin,0149-1423,,,AAPG BULL,Engineering
4,AAPS Journal,1550-7416,,,AAPS J,Medicine
5,Aaps Pharmscitech,1530-9932,,,AAPS PHARMSCITECH,
6,Aatcc Review,1532-8813,,,AATCC REV,
7,Abdominal Imaging,0942-8925,,,ABDOM IMAGING,
8,Abhandlungen Aus Dem Mathematischen Seminar Der Universitat Hamburg,0025-5858,,,ABH MATH SEM HAMBURG,
9,Abstract and Applied Analysis,1085-3375,,,ABSTR APPL ANAL,Math
10,Academic Emergency Medicine,1069-6563,,,ACAD EMERG MED,Medicine
```

What is needed ?

The input above has a column of ISSN numbers. Read the ISSN numbers and search for it in `researchgate.net` or in web. Then wen the individual web pages are found search for `Impact Factor 2015` and retrieve the value put it in the empty place beside ISSN Number and also place the retrieved URL next to it

so that web search can be also limited to one site and one keyword search for the value .. the empty one can be kept as "NAN"

Thanks in advance for the suggestions and help

Comment: Please check web-scraping library for python like beautifulsoup or scrapy. There are huge amount of great tutorials out there of it also. I think pandas tag is little bit inappropriate for your question. After finishing scraping, pandas will be useful though.

Comment: @su79eu7k Thank you for the suggestion to start with .. But Is something like this possible achieve ?

Comment: According to [this](https://blog.hartleybrody.com/web-scraping/) blog post: **"Any content that can be viewed on a webpage can be scraped. Period."** Now, in some cases it might be very difficult to do so, but for a site like yours above, it's certainly doable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code using beautiful soup and urllib2. I am using h2 tag and searching for 'Journal Impact:', but I will let you decide on the algorithm to extract the data. The html content is present in soup and soup provides API to extract it. What I provide is an example and that may work for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

issn = '0219-5305'
url  = 'https://www.researchgate.net/journal/%s_Analysis_and_Applications' % (issn)
htmlDoc = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup    = BeautifulSoup(htmlDoc, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all('h2'):
    if 'Journal Impact:' in tag.text:
        value = tag.text
        value = value.replace('Journal Impact:', '')
        value = value.strip(' *')
        print value
```

Output:

```
   1.13
```

I think the official documentation for beautiful soup is pretty good. I will suggest spending an hour on the documentation if you are new to this, before even try to write some code. That hour spent on reading the documentation will save you lot more hours later.

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Thank you so much .. let me run the script and will reply back the comment .. thanks again ..

Comment: In my case I have a list of ISSN number and no URL to refer .. The main site is known `researchgate.net` and not individual URL from where the `Journal Impact` can be scraped. Here It is scraping from the given URL. So can please help in that direction.

Comment: You can create the URL using the ISSN. I have updated the answer to to create the URL using the ISSN. Does that help?

Comment: This looks like this will work but .. let me have a re run again .. I have a csv file which has 3 columns and one of them is ISSN number .. so we read the ISSN number from that csv column. Search it in `researchgate.net` site and then write the respective `impact factor` value & URL beside ISSN number as a new columns in output CSV. Those which do not have values can we given as NAN. This is what I am trying to do..

Comment: You are on the right track. Enjoy coding it..:)..Do post your code when done..in the question as a final answer....

Comment: Can you please clarify one thing .. The URL of that independent page related to given ISSN number is not available in the csv. In that case what do I put for URL ?

Comment: URL needs to come from some place...If it is not coming from the CSV...you can keep it in your code keyed by the ISN..Let me update the code to show the same..

Comment: My csv has like 50k ISSN numbers but no URL in that .. If I have to give URLs then i might copy the impact factor from that page and update the csv manually .. Which is practically not the easy task ..

Comment: Does URL follows some pattern like all are prefixed with https://www.researchgate.net/journal/ and suffixed with _Analysis_and_Applications. Then you can use python string concatenation to create the URL from the issn. Does that help?

Comment: I have updated the 10 rows from the input in the question .. can you please check then you will see what is available with me .. my search Key is "Impact Factor 2015" and I have find the value and url for that. If it helps better then that can be from any web site..

Comment: I have edited the entire content for better understanding .. And Thanks again for the help with code .. I have accepted it as answer but not sure it that will work for me ..

Comment: error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden